# Different ways to trigger click for a button using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, click, dom-events, sapui5

I have a button which is a SAP UI Element. I want to trigger the click behavior using Javascript. I tried below methods. They did not do the trick. So I am here asking whether there are any other approach to tackle the issue.

```
// Approach 1
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
element.dispatchEvent(evt);

// Approach 2
event = new Event("click", {bubbles: true});
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

I also tried `element.click()`.

PS: The only way its working is using - `sap.ui.getCore().byId( $('#__button6').eq(0).attr("id")).firePress();`

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: AFAIK the .firePress method is the way to go.

Comment: Depends on the purpose. Are you writing some tests? Or for what would you like to "trigger" a button click?

Comment: I have plugin and it clicks the button for some automation purpose. Plugin is external and written in Vanilla Javascript.

Comment: By "plugin", do you mean FLP plugin? Browser plugin? A plugin for which environment?

Comment: Its a separate plugin for that product. dont need to install anything. it comes with that application as a separate JS file but developed by us. so we access the elements by ID or classnames.

Answer (score -1):

You could try `$("#element").trigger( "click" );`